# SQL Query is invalid in the select list

Tags: sql

I dont know why this is coming up as invalid and I can not figure it out.  I was given a legacy database as my supervisor left and I am in charge until someone comes to replace him.  I am trying to run this query...

```
    SELECT     tblM.guidRId, SUM(dbo.tblCH.curTotalCost) AS curValue
FROM         tblCH INNER JOIN
                      tblM ON tblCH.guidMId = tblM.guidMId INNER JOIN
                      ViewLM ON tblM.strNumber = ViewLM.strNumber
WHERE     (tblM.guidRId = '4d832bc8-1827-4054-9896-6111844b0f26')
```

The error I keep getting is...Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'tblM.guidRId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Why is this error occuring?

Comment: you are missing 'group by tblM.guidRId' at the end

Comment: formatting the sql so it'll be more readable would be nice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to group guidRId. (you are aggregating the data)

```
SELECT     
    tblM.guidRId, 
    SUM(dbo.tblCH.curTotalCost) AS curValue
FROM         
    tblCH 
    INNER JOIN tblM ON tblCH.guidMId = tblM.guidMId 
    INNER JOIN ViewLM ON tblM.strNumber = ViewLM.strNumber
WHERE  
    tblM.guidRId = '4d832bc8-1827-4054-9896-6111844b0f26'
GROUP BY tblM.guidRId
```

Comment: Thanks, I was scratching my head over here haha

Answer (score 1):

Because you need a GROUP BY if you are going to use an aggregate functon like SUM() [or COUNT, AVG(), etc...] with another non-aggregate column:

```
SELECT tblM.guidRId, SUM(dbo.tblCH.curTotalCost) AS curValue
FROM   tblCH 
INNER JOIN tblM 
    ON tblCH.guidMId = tblM.guidMId 
INNER JOIN ViewLM 
    ON tblM.strNumber = ViewLM.strNumber
WHERE  tblM.guidRId = '4d832bc8-1827-4054-9896-6111844b0f26'
GROUP BY tblM.guidRId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT
 tblM.guidRId, SUM(dbo.tblCH.curTotalCost) AS curValue
FROM
 tblCH
  INNER JOIN tblM
   ON tblCH.guidMId = tblM.guidMId
  INNER JOIN ViewLM
   ON tblM.strNumber = ViewLM.strNumber
WHERE (tblM.guidRId = '4d832bc8-1827-4054-9896-6111844b0f26')
GROUP BY tblM.guidRId
```